# Does Magento 2.3 supports Dotmailer?

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates

I have gone through some of the documentation and see it is written that the Dotmailer is bundled with Magento 2. But I cannot see the Dotmailer configuration at the admin side. What could be the problem?

Also, Is it possible to test the Dotmailer in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned the github repository then it isn't bundled. It's only when installing via Composer that you get it as a bundled package.

You should be able to `composer require dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension` or clone https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension.